# Batch File Help-Youtube Auto viewer. How to stop loop after specfic amount of time and user input beforehand

Tags: youtube, viewer

Hiya made a simple Youtube autoviewer using notepad*BATCH FILE but i want to have user input--> **so the user can change the link before pressing start**

And i wont it to stop script after its LOOPS 250 times.

```
:top
start /min iexplore.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5DzRTyhs_0
@echo "waiting"
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1>nul
@echo "done waiting"
TASKKILL /F /IM "iexplore.exe"
ipconfig /release /renew
GOTO top
```

So USER CAN CHANGE URL LINK THEN PRESS START.

Many thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=754730 <-- Working EXE version, finlayy finish coding it!

Answer (score 1):

Add after "start /min iexplore.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5DzRTyhs_0":
`set /a number=%number% + 1
if "%number%"=="250" (goto whereever)
if not "%number%"=="250" (goto whereever)`

Answer (score -1):

```
for /L %a in (1,1,10) do @(echo run %a&batch.exe)
```

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/loop-example-cmd-window-t1468124.html